# GCM Push Notification whereby Message is Push From Mobile To GCM Server

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Can any of you all provide a code for GCM Push Notification where the message is pushed from mobile to GCM-Server. I already did from GCM server to Mobile and its working but I don't know how to do it vice versa.. Can anyone provide help? 
Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
data.putString("my_action", "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
```

You can take reference on developer
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-send

Comment: Thanks @calvinfly but where should I insert this code?